# how to copy testset folders from one location to another using OTA

Tags: ota

I have a requirement to copy all the sub folders (along with the test sets within them) as sub folders under another test set folder

```
for eg., lets say i have test set folder

Root\TestSetFolder1 
 ===TestsetSubfolder1
    ----testset1
   ----  testset2
====TestSetSubFolder2
  -----testset3
 ----- testset4

i want all of the subfolders and test sets within those folders to be copied under a new test set folder location ,for eg
Root\TestSetFolder2

so after copy the destination folder should have
Root\TestSetFolder2
 ===TestsetSubfolder1
    ----testset1
   ----  testset2
====TestSetSubFolder2
  -----testset3
 ----- testset4
here is the code`enter code here
how do i recursively copy only the subfolders
```

** Dim tdc, qcServer
    Set tdc = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
    qcServer = "http://server.com"
    tdc.InitConnectionEx qcServer 
    Dim qcUsername As String
    Dim qcPassword As String
    Dim qcDomain As String
    Dim qcProject As String
    Dim treeMng As TestSetTreeManager 
    Dim sourceFolder As testSetFolder 
    Dim destFolder As testSetFolder 
    Dim iscp As ISupportCopyPaste 
    Dim clipboard As String

```
qcUsername =InputBox("Enter QC User Name")
qcPassword = InputBox("Enter QC password")
tdc.Login qcUsername, qcPassword
If (tdc.LoggedIn = false) Then
MsgBox "QC User Authentication failed", vbInformation, "User Authentication"
End If

qcDomain = "FS1"
qcProject = "FQA1"
tdc.Connect qcDomain, qcProject
If (tdc.Connected = failed) Then
MsgBox ("QC Project not connected :" & qcProject), vbInformation, "Project Connection"
End If
call CopyPasteTestSetFolder("Root\F1\F3\F4","Root\F7\test_vb2")
Private Sub CopyPasteTestSetFolder(sourceFolderPath, destFolderPath) 
     Dim treeMng 
     Dim sourceFolder 
     Dim destFolder 
     Dim iscp
     Dim clipboard 
     Set treeMng = tdc.TestSetTreeManager 
     Set sourceFolder = treeMng.NodeByPath(sourceFolderPath) 
     Set destFolder = treeMng.NodeByPath(destFolderPath) 
     Set iscp = sourceFolder 
     clipboard = iscp.CopyToClipBoard(sourceFolder.NodeID, 0, sourceFolderPath) 
     Set iscp = destFolder 
     iscp.PasteFromClipBoard clipboard, destFolder.NodeID, 0, -1 
     Set treeMng = Nothing 
     Set sourceFolder = Nothing 
     Set destFolder = Nothing 
     Set iscp = Nothing 
End Sub `**


This is giving object is required 424 error at "Set treeMng = tdc.TestSetTreeManager " line
```